# Firebird horizontally scaling using containers

Tags: docker, azure, kubernetes, scaling, firebird

I am trying to setup a firebird server within K8s and using docker containers. This has worked well with using Azure Files as a persistent volume storage, however when I try scaling past 1, there are some odd behaviours that occur.

I do not know firebird very well, but it appears to be loading the databases from the single file (like SQLite). Any advice on how I can most stably scale this server?

Comment: Is this even allowed? I've not looked for long but I can't find any reference yet to Firebird being clusterable at all - happy to be wrong.

Comment: Yeah its possible to containerize it, but I am starting to think firebird containers could only be vertically scaled if need be. Reading up on other limitations of like systems makes me think this isnt supported.

Comment: It appears that the file is getting locked every time, while this can occur with multiple instances and a common file share, it degrades performance significantly.

Comment: Sorry I meant clustered not containerised - which would explain the locking.